# MySQL Access violation in Laravel that works in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've just started using Laravel Framework and found a nice little guide for hierarchical-data (through this site) that I have working quite well.

The only problem I've come across is running the following code through Laravel:

```
DB::query("LOCK TABLE pages WRITE;
        SELECT @myLeft := lft FROM pages WHERE id = ?;
        UPDATE pages SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myLeft;
        UPDATE pages SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myLeft;
        UNLOCK TABLES;", 1);
```

Works fine when I run the command through phpmyadmin but in Laravel I get an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

I have many other queries running fine, so I don't know where to begin looking, I've already tried adding ` to the table and field names, and removed the locks to see if that would do anything but no change.

Answer (score 1):

ok I'm thinking Lavarel its wanting to run a single query and I'm trying to run five, when I split the command as below it works,

```
$ord = DB::first("SELECT lft FROM pages WHERE id = ?;", $order);            
        DB::query("UPDATE pages SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > ?;", $ord->lft);
        DB::query("UPDATE pages SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > ?;", $ord->lft);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do only one query per `DB::query()`. Without looking at the source, this method is designed to run only *one* statement.